# Bumped by Community User?

Tags: support, community-user

Maybe I missed it somewhere but what makes the "community user" bump a question?

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11823569/revisions):

> [image]

Answer (score 9):

From [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
>
> Questions with at least 30 days of no activity, at least one answer scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that. Questions that are locked or closed will not be bumped. The Community User will only bump a maximum of one question per hour.

Answer (score 8):

Community will occasionally 'bump' questions that haven't received much attention. From what I've seen, this shows them on the front page, and in the 'active' tab of tag pages.

I haven't seen it make a revision history item before, that might be new.

Comment: The fact the bump is shown in the history appears to be a new addition, indeed.

Comment: Hmmm But the question is ~4 years old.

Comment: @Neal but the feature is new. Old questions have higher chances of being abandoned since there are more and more questions every day and people won't search those things anymore. Bumping it up might make it more useful to some people