# Why has the community user been bumping this question once a month for the last 9 months?

Tags: support, community-user

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237588/why-the-property-border-radius-doesnt-work-anymore-with-overflow-hidden) just got bumped. I've closed it now because it's an old question about a runaway issue in Google Chrome that must have been fixed some time in the last five years since the question was posted, but in the meantime, I notice that the community user has been bumping it [almost exactly once a month for the last **9 months**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14237588/revisions). Other than a single inconsequential comment, there has been absolutely no activity on the question or its answers otherwise.

Why was the question getting bumped so aggressively only since last year? Was it because of the age of the question and the time it spent unanswered?

Comment: Can't tell if this is the same issue as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346604/why-is-the-community-user-so-determined-to-bump-this-question from the suggested questions at the time of asking.

Comment: It looks like the same issue.

Comment: Community is working hard on building a site and can't finish until it gets an answer to this!

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Community needs to tell its users to update their browsers.

Comment: This is the weirdest machine uprising plot I've ever heard of.

Comment: Maybe cross-meta duplicated https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293393/213575

Comment: Jon Skeet needs to answer it so the community user can stop haunting this question

Comment: @WhatsThePoint He hit 1M points. He's probably retiring. I mean, "What's the point?" ;)

Comment: Should there be a bump limit? After X bumps Community should move on to more pressing matters?

Comment: @BilltheLizard, my wife also had a bump for 9 months and then spawned some offspring. Perhaps this _is_ how it starts?

Comment: @krillgar with that attitude he would never hit 2 million

Answer (score 44):

It met all the [bumping criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511)

- question score >= 0
- at least 30 days with no activity
- have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that
- and no accepted answer
- not deleted or closed

These do not expire. As soon as 30 days pass since the last bump (which counts as activity), the post is due for another bump.

A single downvote on the question, if it's no longer useful, would have been enough to stop bumping. Or an upvote to an answer. Or downvotes on both answers.

Yes, there are many more bumping-eligible questions that can be bumped: this was also noted in [Why is the Community User so determined to bump this question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346604/why-is-the-community-user-so-determined-to-bump-this-question) I suppose that the choice among eligible questions is deterministic, probably involving the number of views and/or the number of answers. So it's less like winning a lottery many times in a row and more like standing out in a crowd of candidates.

Comment: Huh. I get that this bumping is presumably meant to encourage voting in order to stop these questions from being classified as "unanswered", but that seems like a pretty meaningless thing to do, and this seems like a way of doing it that is actively hostile to the interests of the community. If you sat down and asked yourself "how can make people's home pages maximally useless by populating them with questions they don't care about or have anything to contribute to but which also don't meet the criteria for closure", bumping stuff that meets these criteria would be the optimal way to do it.

Comment: Are all questions that fulfill the criteria bumped? That seems weird.

Comment: @Braiam in theory, only one question per hour. See the post BoltClock linked in the comment.

Comment: Perhaps an action different from bumping could be taken instead for questions past a certain age threshold.  Such as nothing.  Or maybe even automatic flag or closure.

Comment: @Stijn That means that each 30 days we get 24*30=720 questions. I doubt there would be only 720 questions satisfying the criteria each month.

Comment: I was going to say that it was quite unbelievable that absolutely no one acted on the question despite it getting bumped once a month for a straight 9 months (not even a single close vote, I checked), but then again, it *did* take 9 months of bumping for me to finally see it again after I last touched it more than five years ago.

Comment: But why is always the same question bumped? For example, the question mentioned in this question got bumped every time the Community user had the chance to do so, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40879851/4284627) has never been bumped even though it meets the criteria. I would expect the Community user to make a more varied choice than just bumping the same question 10 times.

Comment: @DonaldDuck My guess is that questions with multiple 0-score answers get to the front of the queue. In any case, the choice of lucky winner of the hour is probably deterministic, so whatever criteria are used lead to the same outcome.