# How many times can a question be bumped by the community user?

Tags: discussion, community-user, bump

Is there a limit to the number of times the question should be bumped by [*Community*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-user/info)? Should it be bumped 5 times? 10 times? Every month? Every 3 months? Is there an official rule for this? Will such question every stop being bumped?

I am being motivated after seeing this question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7705787/revisions

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a limit but yes it's really annoying when you encounter such questions that the system is desperately trying to keep afloat instead of deleting like it should.

Comment: [Once every 3 months](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378736/7296893), and I think it continues indefinitely. But that limit is only in effect since January this year.

Comment: The question stops being bumped if an answer has a score above zero. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334814/1571407 If you can't make an informed upvote, look at the comments, if the OP says it was helpful you may choose to upvote the answer.

Comment: Don't mindlessly upvote stuff though. The answer(s) could be awful